# Pass vue data value in another data value

Tags: vue.js

is this possible that i get Value from one data and pass that to another like this.

```
data: function() {
    return {
          tester: 'tester',
          dropdownBtn: '<span>Sort</span>'+this.tester+'<span class="material-icons">expand_more</span>'
    }
}
```

An answer would be appreciated.

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use computed for this case

```
computed: {
    dropdownBtn() {
        return `<span>Sort</span>${this.tester}<span class="material-icons">expand_more</span>`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it, but a better approach would be to use a function (be it inside computed or methods) to get the value.